# Method Too Large : While upgrading from grails 2.3.7 to grails 2.4.4

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am currently using grails 2.3.7 with java 7, Now I want to upgrade it to grails 2.4.4 with java 8 
But While Upgrading I am getting this error:

```
  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] General error during class generation: Method code too large!
  [groovyc] java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
```

Comment: The Plugins Configuration is like this in BuildConfig.groovy plugins {
        build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
  compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC3'
  compile ":mail:1.0.7"
  compile ":asynchronous-mail:1.2"
  compile ":quartz:1.0.2"
  compile ":asset-pipeline:2.5.7"
  
  
  compile ":jxl:0.54"
  
  
  
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.9" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.4"<meta name="layout" content="dashboard"/>
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
  runtime ":cors:1.3.0"
  runtime "org.grails.plugins:angularjs-resources:1.4.2"
  runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
  
    }

Comment: Can you provide more details and samples of code or the project itself if it is open code? It is hard to say what is going on based only your question.

Comment: I have not changed anything into the code, I just did the migration for my application from grails 2.3.7 to grails 2.4.4 and run the compiler

Comment: I Think some plugins which i have mentioned in BuildConfig are not compatible, But I am unable to find which one.

Comment: Can you either provide any additional information or try to migrate step by step? Migrate to Java8 and make sure that code is okay and later upgrade plugin (unless it exactly how you started).

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to upgrade it to grails 2.4.4 with java 8

Without seeing your project it is hard to say if this is relevant or not but we don't support Java 8 with Grails 2.4.4.  Grails 2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we support Java 8.